# Typescript Command Line Compiler Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to deploy an Ionic Project, where the Main Developer has left the company and there is no documentation whatso ever left. The problem I have is, that there are Typescript Files, but no Typescript Compiler defined or used in Gulp or anything.

So he probably used a local compiler to do this.

I installed the 1.5.3 Version of Typescript via npm. And my goal was to recursively compile all the files in one directory to one Javascript-File.

What I found online is, to use:

```
tsc *.ts --out app.js
```

However I always get the Error:

```
error TS6053: File '*.ts' not found.
```

When I compile a single File it works. And I tried it in different terminals.

EDIT: I need to add I have a map.js File of the target app.js. So I know what I need to compile. Is there a way or tool to reverse engineer using this map file?

EDIT2: Example of a File:

```
/// <reference path="./util.ts"/>
```

///

```
module al.driver {
/**
 * local machine: false
 * smartphone: true
 */
export let cordova = true;

export interface IPreLoadData {
    date:Date;
    id:String;
}

export var preLoadData: IPreLoadData = {
date:Date,
id:String
}

// event conditions
var docReady = false;
var devReady = false;

// Document ready listener
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.info("document ready");
    docReady = true;
    bootstrapApplication();
});



// Initialize Application
function bootstrapApplication() {
    if (docReady && devReady) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["test"]);
    }
}}
```

Comment: are those files using modules imports?

Comment: why not have a tsconfig.json file in the folder you want to compile and have all the configuration needed in that?

Comment: @Maximus they reference using the reference path

Comment: @user5417542, show the contents of a file

Comment: @toskv this would be another option. There is a tsconfig-file already present, but it's just a basic one, without any real information, thus not being used.

Comment: if you have a tsconfig tsc should pick all ts files from the folder and it's subfolders automatically.. if you need more control you should extend that. :)

Comment: @Maximus added an example

Comment: what is this syntax `module al.driver {` ?

Comment: @Maximus that's typescript internal modules syntax. :)

Comment: @toskv ,thanks, where can I read about that?

Comment: @Maximus the handbook's chapter on modules is a good start. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: @user5417542 could you share the contents of your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @toskv, ah, these are namespaces, I've read that they are of no use with the adoption of ES6 modules, so I didn't get into them. thanks

Comment: in any case with a properly configured tsconfig.json file (which is used anyway) it should be enough to just run tsc in the folder.